# Execute code when leaving a tabsheet

Tags: delphi

I'm currently working on a project in Delphi that has two parts: one in which you can register some information and another one in which you can view the information.
There are two TabSheets in a PageControl, both execute different codes. When I leave a tab to go to the other one, I need to execute the closefile() command,  however I do not know which event registers leaving a tabsheet to the other one. I've tried onExit and onHide, but neither worked.

```
procedure TfrmRegister.tbsListExit(Sender: TObject)
begin
if Painting <> nil then
    Painting.CloseFile;
end;
```

The onShow code for the other TabSheet will execute, but this won't. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`TPageControl.OnChanging`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTabControl.OnChanging) event.

> **Occurs immediately before a new tab is selected**.
>
> Write an `OnChanging` event handler to take specific action immediately before the selected tab changes. Set the `AllowChange` parameter to False to prevent the change.
>
> Use an `OnChanging` event handler to prevent the user from leaving a tab setting until certain conditions have been met. **An `OnChanging` event handler can also be used to save information about the current state of the tab control before it is changed by a new tab selection.**
>
> Note: The event is not called if you change the active page in code, for example, by setting the value of `TPageControl.ActivePage`.